# how to define a function type prop in enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, chai, enzyme

I have a component which requires a function type prop, Have any one tried to shallow a component which need function to be defined?

`handleClick: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired`

this is the function definition

```
handleClick: function(){
    this.props.handleClick(this.props.conversation)
      }
```

this is my test

```
wrapper=shallow(<ConversationItem  conversation={conversation1} active={true}/>);
```

how will use this function prop in my enzyme test???

Answer (score 1):

I use a mock for testing. Jest / Sinon have mocking support. An example of test written using Jest and Enzyme is:

```
describe('Add', () => {
  let add;
  let onAdd;

  beforeEach(() => {
    onAdd = jest.fn();
    add = mount(<Add onAdd={onAdd} />);
  });

  it('Button click calls onAdd', () => {
    const button = add.find('button').first();
    const input = add.find('input').first();
    input.simulate('change', { target: { value: 'Name 4' } });
    button.simulate('click');
    expect(onAdd).toBeCalledWith('Name 4');
 });

});
```

More information can be found in the [CodeMentor tutorial](https://www.codementor.io/react/tutorial/unit-testing-react-components-jest-or-enzyme).